# `parse` behaves differently in interactive and non-interactive modes

Tags: r, parsing

I think this might be a bug in `parse`, but wanted to check see if anyone else has a better idea.  In interactive mode (RStudio), the following code works correctly:

```
txt <- 'c("", {
  c(integer(3L), 1:3)           
  c(integer(), 1:3, 1L)         # TRUE
  c(integer(), c(1, 2, 3), 1L)  # TRUE
} )
c("", {
  lst <- list(list( 1,  2), list( 3, list( 4, list( 5, list(6, 6.1, 6.2)))))
} )
c("", {
  TRUE
} )'
saveRDS(
  attr(parse(text=txt, keep.source=TRUE), "srcfile")$parseData, 
  paste0("~/parsecomp", interactive())
)
```

But if I run the exact same code with (runtests.R just contains the code above):

```
R --vanilla < tests/runtests.R
```

The two `rds` files produced by running the original code interactively vs non interactively should be identical, yet:

```
> non.interactive <- readRDS("~/parsecompFALSE")
> interactive <- readRDS("~/parsecompTRUE")
> length(interactive)
[1] 1280
> which(interactive != non.interactive)
[1] 1176
> interactive[which(interactive != non.interactive)]
[1] 0
> non.interactive[which(interactive != non.interactive)]
[1] 234
> identical(attributes(non.interactive), attributes(interactive))
[1] TRUE
```

The parseData result is almost identical (tokens, text, etc. are), but one item is different (I believe the values for `attr(parse(x), "srcFile")$parseData` represent the parent id for each token).  So for some reason running in non-interactive mode mis-attributes the parent id of one token.

I've reduced the code that produced the miss-parsing from hundreds of lines to the above.  Almost any further change/simplification to the code will cause the parse discrepancy to go away.

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this to happen?

This is all on:

```
setting  value                       
version  R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
system   x86_64, darwin13.1.0        
ui       RStudio (0.97.551)
```

---

As per MrFlick's suggestion, here is the output storing the result of `getParseData` (note I'm re-using the same variables names as above to store the results):

```
> subset(interactive, parent != non.interactive$parent)
    line1 col1 line2 col2  id parent token terminal text
226     6    5     8    7 226      0  expr    FALSE     
> subset(interactive, parent != non.interactive$parent)
    line1 col1 line2 col2  id parent token terminal text
226     6    5     8    7 226      0  expr    FALSE     
> subset(non.interactive, parent != interactive$parent)
    line1 col1 line2 col2  id parent token terminal text
226     6    5     8    7 226    234  expr    FALSE     
> subset(non.interactive, id == 234)
    line1 col1 line2 col2  id parent token terminal text
234     9    9     9    9 234    251   ','     TRUE    ,
```

Notice how the `parent` value for the non-interactive version occurs further down in the file that is parsed (line 9 vs line 6 for the problem expression, and I don't think this should be possible).

---

UPDATE: I was able to recreate the problem even more simply, without even the need for a non-interactive version.  Starting with a clean R session where nothing has been done yet (no packages loaded, etc), running:

```
txt <- 'c("", {
  c(integer(3L), 1:3)
  c(integer(), 1:3, 1L)         # TRUE
  c(integer(), c(1, 2, 3), 1L)  # TRUE
} )
c("", {
  lst <- list(list( 1,  2), list( 3, list( 4, list( 5, list(6, 6.1, 6.2)))))
} )
c("", {
  TRUE
} )'
prs1 <- parse(text=txt, keep.source=TRUE)
prs2 <- parse(text=txt, keep.source=TRUE)
which(attr(prs1, "srcfile")$parseData != attr(prs2, "srcfile")$parseData)
```

reproduces the error.  I've reported this to R devel to see if they say anything about it.

Comment: Rather than saving `attr(parse(text=txt, keep.source=TRUE), "srcfile")$parseData`, it's a bit easier to read if you do `getParseData(parse(text=txt, keep.source=TRUE))` But it does look like the interactive mode is doing something funny. It has a parent ID of "7" (in my case) but there is no element with an id of "7" (running R version 3.1.0).

Comment: @MrFlick, good point.  I actually started off with `getParseData`, and only ended up with the above after digging through the sources trying to figure out where the bug was occurring.

Comment: @MrFlick, also interesting I'm getting a different parent ID error than you are.

Comment: You absolutely certain there's nothing in your "non-vanilla" environment which is modding the attributes?  I'm biased, so take this w/ a grain of salt but I'd suspect a bug in RStudio's console before looking too hard at `parse` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I tested in standard R. And it's seems wrong that an element would be assigned a parent ID of an ID that does not exit. (At least what's the problem as I see it)

Comment: @BrodieG R does not promise that multiple calls to `parse()` with the same code will generate the same IDs. Those values are completely arbitrary. You could add five to all those numbers and the object would be have the same way (if you updated the IDs to match). So unless you are directly affected by the fact that you get an undefined parent ID, i doubt you should expect to always get the same IDs. That's not really a bug so much as you are assuming a property of the result that is not defined. There simply is no need to return the exact same ID.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I don't know about my non-vanilla environment, except it is returning the correct answer, whereas the vanilla one is producing the unexpected one.

Comment: In your update, again, I don't think the problem is that the parent IDs are different. There is no promise or guarantee that they will be the same. The problem is that the parent ID is not in the list of IDs: `subset(interactive, !parent %in% id)` (when using `getParseData`). Interestingly, the results seem more consistent when you use a `textConnection` with `parse()` rather than a character literal.

Comment: @MrFlick, I don't disagree.  I think the problem is that the parent ID is just plain wrong, whether not present as an ID, or clearly pointing to something that couldn't possibly be a parent.