# How can I obtain the result of getParseData in a non-interactive call?

Tags: r

I have a little R script containing this:

```
code <- 'write.table(x=iris, file="iris.txt", sep="_")'
sink(file("all.Rout", open = "wt"))
parse(text=code)
str( getParseData(parse(text=code))   )
sink()
```

On Windows (R 3.6.1), I open `cmd`, type `R`, then `source(script.R)`.
The resulting `all.Rout` contains the str of the data.frame I need. The parse result is not displayed but I don't need it. All good.

When in `cmd`, I type `Rscript script.R`, `all.Rout` contains `expression(write.table[...])`, but the result of getParseData is `NULL`. I need the latter for syntax checks in a quiz setting.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing this post ([`parse` behaves differently in interactive and non-interactive modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133551/parse-behaves-differently-in-interactive-and-non-interactive-modes)), the solution is simple:

```
getParseData(parse(text=code, keep.source=TRUE))
```

Apparently, `getOption("keep.source")` is FALSE in non-interactive sessions.